# C++ Passing a tempate typename class as function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, typename

I need to pass a template  class as parameter to a function but i can retrieve the typename inside the function for initialize a temporal variable

the class is declared as follows:

```
template <typename Type> class ListIndex_Linked
```

here is the inicialization of the class in the main and the call of the function

```
ListIndex_Linked<std::string> L;
insertion(L);
```

and what i'm trying to do

```
template <class list <typename Type>>
void insertion( list<Type>& L ) 
{
    Type& temp = L.get(0); 
    {
        int max = L.numElem();
        for ( int i = 1, ; i < max; i++ )
        {

        }
    }
}
```

but i get this error:

```
error: 'list' is not a template
void insertion( list<Type>& L )
             ^
```

thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not declaring `list` as a `template template parameter` correctly.

```
template <template <typename> class list, typename Type>
void insertion( list<Type>& L ) 
{
  ...
}
```

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

Comment: I see, it was very simple, thank you, I tried various combinations with template and typename but without success

Comment: @FernandoPereira You can see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

If `insertion` is only supposed to work with `ListIndex_Linked`, then you can write it as a template in terms if the list's template parameter:

```
template <typename Type>
void insertion(ListIndex_Linked<Type>& L) 
{
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, you can use template template parameters:

```
template<template<class> class List, class Type>
void insertion(const List<Type>& L)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: no I have 3 other classes that work with insertion, i did that before and worked but wasn't what I need

Comment: @FernandoPereira But that is not in your question. You can use template template parameters. I added an example.

Comment: You're right my error I'll be more specific in future questions, thanks

Answer (score 1):

An other way is to use `auto` to not mandate `Type`:

```
template <typename Container>
void insertion(Container& L ) 
{
    auto& temp = L.get(0); 
    {
        int max = L.numElem();
        for ( int i = 1, ; i < max; i++ )
        {

        }
    }
}
```

There is also the `typedef` inside `Container` which may help, something like

```
typename Container::reference temp = L.get(0); // or Container::value_type&
```

which requires something like:

```
template <typename Type>
class ListIndex_Linked
{
public:
    using value_type = Type;
    using reference = Type&;
    // ...
    // Your code
};
```

Comment: Interesting solution, will try it next time to see how it works, thanks!